# Weird issue with JTree.expandPath after removing/replacing the only child

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I conjured up this SSCCE to reproduce some weird behavior I encountered in a larger program:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class TreeExpandTest {

    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TreeExpandTest window = new TreeExpandTest();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public TreeExpandTest() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");
        final JTree tree = new JTree(root);
        tree.setShowsRootHandles(true);
        final DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();
        final DefaultMutableTreeNode level1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Level 1");
        root.add(level1);
        DefaultMutableTreeNode level2a = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Level 2a");
        level1.add(level2a);

        final TreeNode[] nodes = model.getPathToRoot(level1);
        tree.expandPath(new TreePath(nodes));

        frame.getContentPane().add(tree, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton btnDoStuff = new JButton("Remove 2a, replace with 2b");
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnDoStuff, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        btnDoStuff.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                level1.remove(0);
                int[] removed = {0};
                model.nodesWereRemoved(level1, removed, null);

                DefaultMutableTreeNode level2b = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Level 2b");
                level1.insert(level2b, 0);
                int[] inserted = {0};
                model.nodesWereInserted(level1, inserted);

                //tree.collapsePath(new TreePath(nodes));
                tree.expandPath(new TreePath(nodes));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

To fully understand the problem, proceed as follows:

1. Launch the program.
2. Click the button at the bottom.  This is supposed to (i) remove "Level 2a" then (ii) replace it with "Level 2b" and finally (iii) re-expand the "Level 1" node so the newly inserted replacement is visible.
3. After clicking, notice that "Level 1" is collapsed, when it should be expanded.
4. Here's where it gets really weird: click the handle in front of "Level 1" to expand it.  Notice that nothing happens!  Click it once more, and it will finally expand.  This weird behavior leads me to believe that it actually was expanded to begin with, but somehow painted incorrectly.  I am not aware of any way to call for a tree to repaint, and I believe I am calling the `nodesWereInserted` method correctly, which is really all I can do, right?

I found a workaround which "fixes" the problem, but does not satisfy my curiosity.

1. Uncomment the next to last line in the source code, and then launch the program and push the button again.  Notice that it works perfect now.

The question remains... what is going wrong, and why is my workaround needed?  Why should I need to collapse the tree before telling it I want it to be expanded?

Edited to add: this only occurs if I'm removing/replacing an only child.  If there are multiple children and I remove/replace such that the parent is never childless, then every thing behaves as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notification is incorrect, it must be:

```
level1.remove(0);
int[] removed = {0};
Object[] children = new Object[]{level2a};
model.nodesWereRemoved(level1, removed, children);
```

note the array of children instead of null

As an aside, I would recommend to use model api for modifying the node/structure (vs. changing the nodes under its feet) whereever possible. For single node changes the above would be:

```
model.removeNodeFromParent(level2a);
DefaultMutableTreeNode level2b = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Level 2b");
model.insertNodeInto(level2b, level1, 0);
```

Comment: Yep, that does it.  Thanks.  Not sure I understand why that exact mistake would cause the problem I was seeing, but not sure that is important either.  I guess I deserve this one for ignoring a parameter, but it sure seems like a weird choice to require both the index of the object removed AND a reference to the object itself.  Seems unnecessarily redundant.  Regardless, thanks again.

Comment: the point is that the event is fired _after_ the node is removed - a listener keeping a cache of the structure (such as LayoutCache in the ui) couldn't do internal cleanup without knowing the instance that has been removed (the index alone doesn't help)

Comment: Ok, I get it.  And thanks for your extra edit you just added.  Seems like that is indeed a smarter way to make changes, a heck of a lot less code too.